# Does Google Gears Allow Metadata Access

Tags: metadata, google-gears

Loving Gears, but does anyone here know how to access Google Gears metadata? Like system tables or tables that will show me a list of the tables within the database?

Thanks!

Comment: Google Gears is being abandoned by Google BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, after doing some research I found the link to this article. http://www.techspot.com/news/37170-google-to-quietly-move-away-from-gears-adopt-html-5.html

Answer (score 1):

Google Gears data cannot be accessed from inside a web application. However you can find the files on your harddisk, and as they are in SQLLite format you should be able to play with them.

Note that Google Gears has more or less been end-of-lived. Google is moving to HTML5 for storing data locally. (Although it will be around for quite some time no doubt)

From the [Google Gears FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_faq.html):

What do the files do?

localserver.db - This is a SQLite database that keeps track of all files that are stored in the LocalServer across all domains. This file is used in the internals of the Gears code, and cannot be accessed from within a Gears program.

permissions.db - This is a SQLite database that keeps track of all domains that have been allowed to use Gears.